# Django: How to upload file without UnicodeEncodeError on save()?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, locale, python-unicode

IM try to upload a file but when the file name have caracters like "ó" have a 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 59: ordinal not in range(128)
im try to `obj.file = smart_unicode(form.cleaned_data["file"])` before save() on views.py

and

```
def file(instance, filename):
    i = datetime.now()
    filename = smart_unicode(filename)

    return "archivos/files/%s_%s" % (str("a")+i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), filename)
```

on models.py, but when using view.py dont have error and on saved model have the name file correct but dont have file, and when not using smart_unicode have error, with out especial caracter font have problem to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this url have information about, [Django: How to upload file without UnicodeEncodeError on save()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546482/django-how-to-upload-file-without-unicodeencodeerror-on-save)

an for me work this:

```
import locale
import sys

def my_views(request):
    # before 
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```